# Billing.subscription.renewed webhook is not being triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

So I'm trying to know which paypal webhook is being sent when the user successfully paid for another billing cycle.

I have a daily subscription plan right now the user was successfully charged but the  Billing.subscription.renewed webhook was not triggered

My question is which webhook is sent when a the customer pays for the new billing cycle on paypal

Answer (score 1):

No `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.RENEWED` webhook exists; subscriptions do not need to be renewed and have either a fixed or unlimited duration. You can find an actual list of all existing webhooks here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions . The list is current.

When there is a payment made on a subscription, the event name is `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` as described there.

Comment: As you see here when you add a webhook in the sandbox there is an event called subscription renewed https://ibb.co/41Xz4yD

Comment: There is a checkbox for something that was going to be named that, yes, but that something doesn't exist

Comment: So How Should I track that a user paid for a new cycle ? PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is fired when any payment is done either it was a subscription or not

Comment: Try examining the details that come along with the webhook event